# How to eliminate the middle column generated by objdump?

Tags: assembly, text, disassembly, objdump

[image]

Platform is on 32 bit Linux, I use objdump to disassemble a binary, and trying to re-use the **address column** and **assemble code columns** , but after searching in the objdump's manual,  I can not find how to force objdump to not output the hex code columns..

I also consider writing some scripts to trim off the unnecessary column, but it seems not a very straight forward work, basically how can I distinguish from hex code and assemble code?

Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: Pipe into [cut](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/)...

Comment: You're welcome. In Linux you should think of each tool doing one specific job. If you want to filter/re-arrange the output, you can always pipe into other commands that can give you your exact desired result. This *composition* way of thinking is common in UNIX-like systems, always think about it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
objdump -j .text -M intel -Dr hello | grep "^ " | cut -f2,3
```

Comment: You're welcome, but I removed your thanks, no need :)